# How to install corebuild in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, opam

I have installed `opam`, and after this I can access `ocaml`, `ocamlc`, `buildocaml` successfully.

But I am reading [Real World OCaml](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144932391X) which is asking me to run a tool called `corebuild`.

I am not able to install (or run) `corebuild`.

If I search for `sudo find / -name corebuild...` I can see files like

```
/home/abhishek/.opam/repo/default/packages/core/core.109.38.00/files/corebuild  
/home/abhishek/.opam/repo/default/packages/core/core.109.42.00/files/corebuild  
/home/abhishek/.opam/repo/default/packages/core/core.109.35.00/files/corebuild  
/home/abhishek/.opam/repo/default/packages/core/core.109.34.00/files/corebuild  
/home/abhishek/.opam/repo/default/packages/core/core.109.47.00/files/corebuild  
/home/abhishek/.opam/repo/default/packages/core/core.109.41.00/files/corebuild  
/home/abhishek/.opam/repo/default/packages/core/core.109.32.00/files/corebuild  
/home/abhishek/.opam/repo/default/packages/core/core.109.37.00/files/corebuild  
/home/abhishek/.opam/repo/default/packages/core/core.109.45.00/files/corebuild  
/home/abhishek/.opam/repo/default/packages/core/core.109.36.00/files/corebuild  
/home/abhishek/.opam/repo/default/packages/core/core.109.40.00/files/corebuild
```

But still then I don't know how to run this tool.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to run `opam install core` to get `corebuild`.

More generally, you should look at the install instructions [here](https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions), which will show you which libraries to install.  Note that `corebuild` is a simple wrapper around `ocamlbuild`, and it assumes that you have `core` installed, and gives you the option of using it by default.